# How to increase exposed filter speed?

Tags: ajax, views

I have three better exposed filter in views.when apply any filter it takes 4 to 5 secs to give a result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Views Cache to make better performance. [image]

Click on Caching in right side of view edit page

Comment: its not working perfectly fine.